# Google Reports API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api

I need to create simple Java application for Reports API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive)

1. But I can't understand is this Reports available only for business users or also for all users?

How can I develop applications for G suite without buy it?

2. For example, I'm sending this request via Postman - https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive

Response is

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "authError",
                "message": "Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records.",
                "locationType": "header",
                "location": "Authorization"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records."
    }
}
```

Best regards,
Aleksandr.

Comment: You'll probably hit that error if the one requesting is not an admin for your domain. For your first question, AFAIK you have to buy it in order to be able to develop G-Suite applications. You can also try the [Google for Nonprofits](https://www.thedigitalnonprofit.com/blog/what-google-nonprofits), if you are a NPO that qualifies for this program.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Rebot for response! About "not admin for domain". Maybe I need some additional parameters for request?